# Show that $W=U_1\oplus U_2\implies W=U_1+U_2$ and $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

> Let $(\mathbb R,V,+)$ be a vector space, where $U_1,U_2\subset V$. We prove that 
>   $$
> W=U_1\oplus U_2\iff W=U_1+U_2\text{ and }U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}.
> $$
>   "$\implies$": Assume $W=U_1\oplus U_2$. For any vector $w\in W$, there are unique vectors $u_1\in U_1$ and $u_2\in U_2$ such that $w=u_1+u_2$. Then for sure $W=U_1+U_2$. [...]

I'm confused by the way the theorem is worded. Shouldn't it go like this:
$$
W=U_1\oplus U_2\implies W\subset U_1+U_2,
$$
and
$$
U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}\iff U_1\oplus U_2=U_1+U_2.
$$

My motivation:

We know that $W=U_1\oplus U_2\implies W\subset U_1+U_2$. Assume $U_1\cap U_2\neq \{0\}$. That means that $\exists v: v\in U_1$ and $v\in U_2$. But then $v=v+0=0+v$, so we have that $v\notin U_1\oplus U_2$. So if $U_1\cap U_2\neq \{0\}$, we know that $W\neq U_1+U_2$.

Now assume $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$. Let $v=u_1+u_2=u_1'+u_2'$, where $u_1,u_1'\in U_1$ and $u_2,u_2'\in U_2$. Let's do some algebra:
\begin{align}
u_1+u_2&=u_1'+u_2'\\
u_1-u_1'&=u_2'-u_2.
\end{align}
We know that $u_1-u_1'\in U_1$ and $u_2'-u_2\in U_2$. Because they are equal, we know that $u_1-u_1'=u_2'-u_2\in U_1\cap U_2$. But that means that $u_1-u_1'=u_2'-u_2=0$. Thus $u_1=u_1'$ and $u_2=u_2'$. Therefore $W=U_1+U_2$.

Comment: What is your definition? This is frequently taken to be the definition.

Comment: @AndresMejia Instead of working with the intersection, we define the direct sum by saying $v=v_1+v_2$ can only be written in a unique way. I see now that these two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $U_1, U_2$ as vector subspaces of $W$. Take the following homomorphism:

$$\phi:U_1 \times U_2 \to W$$
$$(u_1,u_2) \mapsto u_1+u_2.$$

$u_1+u_2=0$ or $(u_1,u_2) \in \ker \phi$ if and only if $u_1=-u_2$, in which case $u_1 \in U_2$ since both are vector subspaces. Hence, $u_1 \in U_1 \cap U_2$. Similarly, we can show that $U_1 \cap U_2 \subseteq \ker \phi$.** Hence, we can conclude that
$$\ker \phi= U_1 \cap U_2.$$

Hence, this function is noninjective, only when its kernel (the intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2$) is non-trivial.

**There is a slight abuse of notation here.

Comment: You surely meant to write: this function is noninjective when its kernel is non-trivial?

Comment: @ShaVuklia haha yes, that is certainly the case.

Comment: @AndresMejia : I read this trying to understand the equivalent definitions of free modules. Perhaps this is evident, but how do we show $U_1\cap U_2\subset \operatorname{ker}\phi$ without assuming $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$? $\phi((u_1,u_2))=u_1+u_2$ s.t. $u_1, u_2\in U_1\cap U_2$, how is $u_1+u_2=0$ necessarily? Am I missing something obvious?